# Is it possible to reference property name in enum from another AJV definitions?

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

I'm looking if it's possible to *reference* property names as `enum` values in AJV definitions.

Here is an example:

```
{
  "$id": "modes.json",
  "description": "Example modes",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "MODE_WALK": { "$ref": "walk.json" },
    "MODE_BICYCLE": { "$ref": "bicycle.json" },
  }
}
```

Then I have another file with:

```
{
  "$id": "another.json",
  "description": "Example object",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "text": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 128
    },
    "mode": {
      "description": "Allowed modes",
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "MODE_WALK",
        "MODE_BICYCLE"
      ]
    },
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["text", "mode"]
}
```

Right now, `enum` has hardcoded values: `MODE_WALK` and `MODE_BICYCLE` - can I reference property names from the first file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this using JSON Schema.

You may consider a pre-processing step to build your schemas.

A common approach to this is to use Jsonnet: https://jsonnet.org

It has been sucessfully used in large scale projects such as the UK GOV website publication platform.