# Parameterising keys in json schema (v7)

Tags: jsonschema

I have a number of json structures that I validate against JSON schema v7, the schemas are pretty complicated and so split over dozens of files. Between them, the structures repeat one or more of the same key names and I'd like to define that key name once and once only, so that I can change it at some future date with minimal fuss. Whilst this is is straightforward for *values*, e.g.

```
"myValue": { "enum": ["VALUE1", "VALUE2"] },

...

"object1": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "myKey": { "$ref": "#/myValue" }
    ...
  }
},
"object2": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "myKey": { "$ref": "#/myValue" }
    ...
  }
},
...
```

and if I change `VALUE2` to `VALUE3` all my schemas are automatically updated, which is nice. But what I also want to do is paramaterise the *key* itself so that it only needs changing in one place, something akin to

```
"myKey": { "const": "MyKey" }

"object1": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    { "$ref": "#/myKey" }: { "$ref": "#/myValue" }
...
```

with the effect of all schemas seeing that `myKey` should now be `MyKey`. But this is obviously not valid JSON since keys must be strings. Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: What you want to do is not possible within the use of JSON Schema. Sorry.

Comment: shame :( would have allowed me to do away with hard-coded key strings in all the code (node.js and C++ in this case) that generates the json - I could instead have referenced the parameterised key in the schema

Comment: Did you look at my answer to a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60864336/89211

Comment: yes I did thanks. I'll have a think about the implications of a preprocessing step